# vb.net efficiently finding byte sequence in byte array

Tags: vb.net

so I am creating a piece of software that in short, has a list of original byte sequences and new sequences that those bytes need to be changed into, kinda like this in text form "original location(currently irrelevant as sequence can be in different places) $ 56,69,71,73,75,77  :  56,69,71,80,50,54"

I already have code that works fine, however there can be up to 600+ of these sequences to find and change and in some cases it is taking a really really long time 15 mins +, i think it is down to how long it is taking to find the sequences to them change so i am trying to find a better way to do this as currently it is unusable due to how long it takes.

I have copied the whole code for this function below in hopes one of you kind souls can have a look and help =)

Dim originalbytes() As Byte

`Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    fd.Title = "Select the file"

    fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"

    fd.FilterIndex = 2

    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        TextBox2.Text = fd.FileName

        originalbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fd.FileName)


    End If


    Dim x As Integer = 0

    Dim y As Integer = 0

    Dim textbox1array() = TextBox1.Lines

    Dim changedbytes() = originalbytes

    Dim startvalue As Integer = 0

    Dim databoxarray() As String

    Dim databoxarray2() As String

    While x < textbox1array.Length - 1

        'for each change to make

        databoxarray = textbox1array(x).Replace(" $ ", vbCr).Replace("  :  ", vbCr).Split

        databoxarray2 = databoxarray(1).Replace(",", vbCr).Split

        Dim databox2bytes() As String = databoxarray2

        'copy original bytes line to databox2 lines
        y = 0

        While y < (originalbytes.Length - databox2bytes.Length)

            'repeat for all bytes in ori file - size of data to find

            If originalbytes(y) = databox2bytes(0) Then

                startvalue = y

                Dim z As String = 1

                Dim samebytecounter As Integer = 1

                While z < databox2bytes.Length

                    'repeat for all ori bytes

                    If originalbytes(y + z) = databox2bytes(z) Then

                        samebytecounter = samebytecounter + 1

                    End If

                    z = z + 1

                End While

                If samebytecounter = databox2bytes.Length Then

                    'same original data found, make changes

                    Dim bytestoinsert() As String = databoxarray(2).Replace(",", vbCr).Split

                    Dim t As Integer = 0

                    While t < bytestoinsert.Length

                        changedbytes(startvalue + t) = bytestoinsert(t)

                        t = t + 1

                    End While

                End If

            End If

            y = y + 1

        End While

        x = x + 1

    End While

    File.WriteAllBytes(TextBox2.Text & " modified", changedbytes)`

Comment: Any chance you could add some potential test data, and values that you enter in the different text boxes? I also don't see where you define `originalbytes`. If this is working code, maybe it would be better to post this question on codereview

Comment: sorry yes the original bytes is loaded as a byte array in another function, unfortunately i can't share one of the files as they are private =(

Comment: Could you at least share it's definition and object type?

Comment: this code is defiantly can be extremely improved, can you show us an example of the input and the requested output? also, do not use textbox, use a variable, writing to textbox is defecting efficiency .

Comment: added to the post the code where i defined the originabytes and get the data

Comment: sorry jonathana at what textbox do you mean? the only time i used a textbox was at the start and its not one of the repeated codes so i though it wouldn't effect it much (note some arrays actually have textbox in the name as i converted them into arrays midway in developing as i was originally using textboxes to visualise the data)

Comment: actually you seem to use it in the first while loop

Comment: @TakeyaSaito if its just for the file path its ok (thought it was to show data), but again, can you show us an example for input string from the file and an example of the requested output, no code needed just the examples.

Comment: @Icepickle that is actually an array declared above, i just pass the textbox to the array when i declare it as to not use the textbox multiple times

Comment: @jonathana here is an example, original bytes
 "2,157,2,23,3,169,3,36,255,110,255,182,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0" expected output "2,157,2,179,3,98,4,36,255,110,255,182,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0" data in textbox1 would be "2129968 $ 2,157,2,23,3,169,3,36,255,110,255,182,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  :  2,157,2,179,3,98,4,36,255,110,255,182,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 's take a look at that inner while loop in your code, there are some things that can be optimized:

There is no need to check the total length all the time

```
Dim length as Integer = originalbytes.Length - databox2bytes.Length
While y < length


    'repeat for all bytes in ori file - size of data to find
    If originalbytes(y) = databox2bytes(0) Then
        startvalue = y
```

`z` is not necessary, samebytecounter does exactly the same

```
        Dim samebytecounter As Integer = 1
```

This while loop is a real bottleneck, since you always check the full length of your databox2bytes, you should rather quit the while loop when they don't match

```
        While samebytecounter  < databox2bytes.Length AndAlso originalbytes(y + samebytecounter ) = databox2bytes(samebytecounter )
            samebytecounter = samebytecounter + 1
        End While
```

This seems fine, but you already splitted the data at the top of your while loop, so, no need to create another array that does the same operation again

```
        If samebytecounter = databox2bytes.Length Then
            'same original data found, make changes
            Dim t As Integer = 0
            While t < databoxarray2.Length
                changedbytes(startvalue + t) = databoxarray2(t)
                t = t + 1
            End While
        End If
    End If
    y = y + 1
End While
```

For the rest I would agree that the algorithm you created is hugely inefficient, theoretically your code could have been rewritten like eg: (didn't really test this code)

```
Dim text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalbytes, 0, originalbytes.Length)
dim findText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringToFind, 0, stringToFind.Length)
dim replaceWith = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringToSet, 0, stringToSet.Length)

text = text.Replace( findText, replaceWith )

dim outbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)
```

which would probably be a huge time saver.

For the rest your code seems to be created in such a way that nobody will really understand it if it's laying around for a month or so, I would say, including yourself

Comment: thank you very much, this has given me some great ideas and highlighted some issues with the original code, sorry for the messy code wasn't really meant for others to see and understand when i first did it =S

Comment: @TakeyaSaito You are welcome, if it helped you, you can [mark it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @jonathana Yeah, though the bytes named variables are hugely disturbing in this code, it makes it really hard what is really in there when they are defined as a string array